# WebSockets work fine in local server but fail when deploy on Pivotal cloud

Tags: spring-websocket, cloud-foundry

It works ok when I deploy on my local server, work fine with any browsers, but when I deploy on Pivotal cloud, it's fail as below console log:

***Console.log error:***

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://bmwbics.apps.pivotal.com/connect/sockjs/735/l8r_friu/websocket' failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1`

**Update other developers have issue like me.
I have set up wrong url_prefix to initialize SocketJS.**

**At this time, I do not what is difference between url_prefix of pivotal and my local**.

**After that I have updated the way getting url_prefix as code below and it works fine.**

Javascript code:

```
var protocol = location.protocol;
var hostname = location.hostname;
var port = location.port;
var url_prefix = protocol + "//" + hostname + (port === '' ? '' : ':' + port) + contextPath;
var sock = new SockJS(url_prefix + '/connectsocket');
```

Java configuration code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
   private static final int MESSAGE_SIZE_LIMIT = 1024 * 1024;
   private static final int SEND_BUFFER_SIZE_LIMIT = 1024 * 1024;
   private static final int SEND_TIME_LIMIT = 10 * 10000;
   @Override
   public final void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
      registry.addEndpoint("/connectsocket").withSockJS();
   }
   @Override
   public final void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
      config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
      config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/");
   }
   @Override
   public final void configureWebSocketTransport(final WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
      registration.setMessageSizeLimit(MESSAGE_SIZE_LIMIT);
      registration.setSendBufferSizeLimit(SEND_BUFFER_SIZE_LIMIT);
      registration.setSendTimeLimit(SEND_TIME_LIMIT);
   }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue with Web sockets on PCF ? I'm facing the same issue. I'm getting 403 Forbidden when I try to connect to the service deployed on Pivotal Cloud. On localhost it works fine.